# Remesh doing weird things?

Tags: remesh

I'm new to Blender. I've looked at other similar questions but I haven't found anything that directly solves my specific problem. (Sorry if I missed something) Remeshing to .01 does this weird thing to my geometry and I'm wondering if there's a way around it or if I'm doing something wrong. Any advice would be appreciated!

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: It's because the details are too thin, you probably can't avoid that with this kind of remesh, maybe try Quad instead of Voxel to see if it works better, or maybe you can correct it manually?